# No nearby results using Google’s place API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to load google places on my app. Currently I'm using the method below to make a request

```
public PlacesList performSearch() throws IOException {
        PlacesList places = null;
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(transport);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactorybuildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.url.put("key", API_KEY);
        request.url.put("location", latitude + "," + longitude);
        request.url.put("radius", area);
        request.url.put("sensor", "true");
        request.url.put("types","night_club|bar|cafe"); 
        places = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        return places;
}
```

The problem is that no data is returned. Is there any other way to load nearby places, because as you know, Places app loads nearby places perfectly?

Comment: What is the value of your PLACES_SEARCH_URL?

Comment: The url is: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?

Comment: Try adding perhaps the url is garbled (double ??)?
Log.d("Sometag","--> request url is: " + request.url.get());

Comment: The url after logging is:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=API_KEY&location=46.0852567,14.5136214&radius=5000&sensor=true&types=night_club%7Cbar%7Ccafe

Comment: did u solve that problem,even I am not getting any data from server.I am getting zero results.

Comment: I didn't found any solution. Currently I'm searching with keyword and types. It looks that if you provide only types does not return any data. request.url.put("keyword","bar");  request.url.put("types","bar");